# XSLT sort childs of two different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I am very new to xslt and I am stuck in a problem I need to sort child nodes no matter what parent they have and display the content arranged. So the XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<report>
    <rowsbypage>5</rowsbypage><!--added to complete the solution-->
    <contenido>
        <page>
            <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
            <row regnum="0">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[8]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[8]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[CTA:Financials]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[CTA:Financials]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="1">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[9]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[9]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[CTA:HR]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[CTA: RH]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="2">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[7]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[7]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[CTA:Accounting]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[CTA:Accounting]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="3">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[2]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[2]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[CTA:Shop]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[CTA:Shop]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="38">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[3]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[3]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[P:Admins]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[P:Admins]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
        </page>
        <page>
            <pagenumber>2</pagenumber>
            <row regnum="39">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[1]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[P:Sys]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[P:Sys]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="40">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[5]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[5]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[P:Dir]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[P:Dir]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="41">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[6]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[6]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[P:Ge]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[P:Ge]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
            <row regnum="42">
                <column name="group_id"  type="number">
                    <value><![CDATA[4]]></value>
                    <group_id type="number"><![CDATA[4]]></group_id>
                </column>
                <column name="group_name"  type="text">
                    <value><![CDATA[P:Req]]></value>
                    <group_name type="text"><![CDATA[P:Req]]></group_name>
                </column>
            </row>
        </page>
    </contenido>
</report>
```

And I need to sort to get:

```
Page 1
Group ID             Group Name
   1                 P:Sys
   2                 CTA:Shop
   3                 P:Admins
   4                 P:Req
   5                 P:Dir
Page2
Group ID             Group Name
   6                 P:Ge
   7                 CTA:Accounting
   8                 CTA:Financials
   9                 CTA:HR
```

I will appreciate any help on this, Kind Regards

Thank you for your responses with the help of both Joel and Michael I ended with this, I add a tag with the number of rows by page and the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="report/contenido/page" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dopaging">
        <xsl:param name="pageNumber" />
        <xsl:for-each select="../page/row" >
                <xsl:sort select="column/value" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() &gt; ($pageNumber - 1) * /report/rowsbypage and position()  &lt;= $pageNumber * /report/rowsbypage">
                                <xsl:for-each select="column" >
                                <div><xsl:value-of select="value" /></div>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pagenumber" >
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
        <xsl:variable name="pageNumber" select="pagenumber" />
        <div>
                <div>Page <xsl:value-of select="$pageNumber" /></div>
                <xsl:call-template name="dopaging">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pageNumber" select="$pageNumber" />
                </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ok after the last comment of Michael that for each page sort all the records again and again, the final XSL looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1" version="5.0" />
    <xsl:template match="/" >
            <xsl:variable name="rowsByPage" select="report/rowsbypage" />
            <xsl:variable name="rows">
                    <xsl:for-each select="report/contenido/page/row" >
                            <xsl:sort select="column/group_id" data-type="number" />
                            <div>
                            <xsl:for-each select="column" >
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="value"/></div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rows)/div[position() mod $rowsByPage = 1]" >
                    <div>
                    <div>Page <xsl:value-of select="position()" /></div>
                    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::div[position() &lt; $rowsByPage]">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** What determines the page number assigned to each group after sorting? **2.** Do you really want a **text** output as shown?

Comment: 1. The page number is assigned by the number of rows a page can contains, 2. No the example here is simple the output is on a html grid.

Comment: In this example a page can contains only 5 rows.

Comment: IIUC, your solution assumes the number of pages in the input is equal to the number of pages required for the output. This was never stated. Note also that you sort all the rows anew for each page.

Comment: I did not comment about the number of pages in the input data because in my original post I did not have such data, but after your questions and saw the Joel solution I notice the need of that parameter, is easy to add the number of pages so I guess is valid to add this data. In regard about that through each page I sort all the rows again it is right, there are some better way to do this?, I will appreciate any comment about this and again thanks for everything

Comment: **Re the number of pages:** I am not sure we are speaking of the same thing. You create a new page for every old one. If the input had only a single page with more than 5 rows, your solution would not return the expected result. Perhaps that's a scenario that cannot happen - but we weren't told that, and if someone reads this they need to be told, IMHO. **Re the repeated sorting:** Yes, I think there's a better way and I have posted it. ;-)

Comment: Michel, I try again your solution and is working like a charm, I can see in your solution I sort rows once. I will adapt my solution to yours is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the output is on a html grid.

I am not quite sure what "a html grid" is.The following stylesheet provides XML output - converting it to HTML (table or any other structure) should be fairly trivial.

The main issue here is that you need to do this in two passes: first, sort the rows; then aggregate the sorted rows into pages, 5 at a time.

**XSLT 1.0 (requires support of the EXSLT node-set() function:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="report/contenido/page/row">
    <xsl:sort select="column/group_id"/>
        <group>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="column/group_id"/></id>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="column/group_name"/></name>
        </group>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<output>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rows)/group[position() mod 5 = 1]">
        <page pagenum="{position()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::group[position() &lt; 5]"/>
        </page>
    </xsl:for-each>
</output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <page pagenum="1">
      <group>
         <id>1</id>
         <name>P:Sys</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>2</id>
         <name>CTA:Shop</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>3</id>
         <name>P:Admins</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>4</id>
         <name>P:Req</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>5</id>
         <name>P:Dir</name>
      </group>
   </page>
   <page pagenum="2">
      <group>
         <id>6</id>
         <name>P:Ge</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>7</id>
         <name>CTA:Accounting</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>8</id>
         <name>CTA:Financials</name>
      </group>
      <group>
         <id>9</id>
         <name>CTA: RH</name>
      </group>
   </page>
</output>
```

Comment: am I missing something, when I run xsltproc with your xsl and my xml I just get </output> tag.

Comment: @user3344938 "*am I missing something*" Probably, but I don't know what. The above was tested with Xalan, Saxon **and** libxslt - which is what xsltproc uses, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code below. I am unsure about your required output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="value group_id group_name"/>

    <xsl:template name="first_group">
        <xsl:variable name="page1_count" select="count(../page[1]/row)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../page/row">
                <xsl:sort select="column/value"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() &lt;= $page1_count">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise/>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="second_group">
        <xsl:variable name="page1_count" select="count(../page[1]/row)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../page/row">
            <xsl:sort select="column/value"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() &gt; $page1_count">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise/>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="page">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pagenumber"/>
            <row>
                <column>Group ID</column>
                <column>Group Name</column>
            </row>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::page) + 1 = 1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="first_group"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="second_group"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly, I will analyze your XSL, it works great, thank you very much.